# Display Bootstrap breakpoint name when resizing the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

I use **Bootstrap 5** to develop a *responsive application*:

It has [6 breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints)

- `xs`
- `sm`
- `md`
- `lg`
- `xl`
- `xxl`

It would be very handy, if the chrome dev-tools could show me the abbreviation of the current width.

For example here. See "XX"

[image: chrome-devtools-add-bootstrap-]

I know that I can modify my HTML to get to the result, but a solution without changing the HTML I am working on would be very cool.

In above example the width is `474` which is less than `576px`, this means the name of the breakpoint would be `xs`.

Answer (score 12):

This is what I use. It help me even when not in inspect mode and keep working even you change breakpoints using bs variables.

```
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(247, 201, 241, 0.4);
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
">
    <div class="d-block d-sm-none">Extra Small (xs)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">Small (sm)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">Medium (md)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">Large (lg)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-xl-block d-xxl-none" >X-Large (xl)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-xxl-block" >XX-Large (xxl)</div>
</div>
```

[image: in action]

Comment: Nice! Never had thought of that :p

Comment: super cool, it shows at the bottom in low-profile even if we forget to get rid of it before going to prod, but I would add comment in code that this is DEBUG only for those copy-pasting!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Natwar Singh's answer, to make it even more "bootstrapy" and to make sure we don't write any `css` ourselves , I have this :

```html
<div class="position-fixed text-nowrap rounded-3 p-1 m-3 bg-info opacity-50">
  <div class="d-block d-sm-none">Extra Small (xs)</div>
  <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">Small (sm)</div>
  <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">Medium (md)</div>
  <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">Large (lg)</div>
  <div class="d-none d-xl-block d-xxl-none">X-Large (xl)</div>
  <div class="d-none d-xxl-block">XX-Large (xxl)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know the default breakpoints with Bootstrap 5.x you can apply some simple CSS to your project to achieve something similar.  In the below code sample I have a class named `.debug` which you could apply to any element (I would recommend `<body>` for your needs).

What it does is fairly simple: it creates an absolute positioned pseudo element that we apply `content: ""` to at specific breakpoints to convey which breakpoint we've hit.

```css
.debug::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 0px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "XS"; }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "SM"; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "MD"; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "LG"; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "XL"; }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) { 
  .debug::before { content: "XXL"; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="debug">
  <h1>You'll want to see this in fullscreen to test it out!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be cool to have this as a chrome plugin, so that I don't need to modify my html files.